# Getting iOS app-private folder Library from the absolute path of Document folder

Tags: java, ios, swift, substring, app-folder

I need to get the complete path of the "Library" private app folder for iOS app.

In Swift I would access that position with

```
 let dir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true);
```

and then

```
 let fileUrl = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("json");
```

I read on StackOverflow that the kind of path is like

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/strangenumberslike...EF22-EB33-4B65-9772-67ED7870E3E9/Library/
```

where the question did refer to "Document" (so the example could be wrong).

My need is getting the Library folder in that form in a cross-platform environment that cannot retrieve it directly, but it has the Document absolute path.

I think that it is just matter of substrings (JAVA), being said that the folder has the same "root".

Maybe

```
String root=documentPath.substring(0,documentPath.indexOf("Document"));
String libraryPath=root+"/Library";
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You should always recreate the URL.Your app is sandboxed so the path will change every time you launch the app

Comment: @Leo Dabus Yes, you are right, I meant that every time the path is calculated with substrings according to the current value of Document path. Would it work, which is the correct Library path when stripped of the ID? Is it the same with just the replacement of the last folder name?